# Should we roll back 62 edits where [russian] was added?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Someone just created the [russian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian) tag and mass-edited it into 62 questions. Should the edits be rolled back? My impression was that spoken languages aren't allowed as tags.

Comment: This tag excerpt makes little to no sense.

Comment: related.. apparently there is a tag [tag:arabic] with about 1600 questions too and [tag:hindi] with 200 questions... Are we having language related tags?

Comment: I can see some wiggle room for _alphabets_, not really for languages though. Alphabets can be related to programming if you have some kind of issue dealing with handling or displaying them (RTL etc).

Comment: Related, from MSE: [Tags for natural languages help in content categorization and searching of posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179681/7586)

Comment: The tag excerpt is far too broad as of now. I could see use in a tag about russian characters, but that’s what the [tag:cyrillic] tag is already providing. I vote for burninating the [tag:russian] tag.

Comment: Most of these question are general, mainly related to encoding. There are a few where the Russian tag might make sense, for example [Parse Months In Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13475419/7586), or [SpellChecker, Russian language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10734180/7586).

Comment: Russian language, as whole or in parts, is never on topic. That's all there is. There's no one able to answer any question about russian without craptons of context, and such context has better, unambiguous and concrete tags already.

Comment: I'll write answer today later, please don't do roll back before

Comment: @SurajRao: Arabic is a language with complex Unicode text layout, so questions about such Arabic script are entirely appropriate and probably deserve a tag. Russian, as I understand, is not a complex text layout language, so there's not much need for the tag.

Comment: The user got the taxonomist badge for his efforts https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=4318868

Comment: ... "I did not wait for anything or anyone before forcibly editing the tag in but now please all wait for me before removing this". Coupled with gaining the badge, it's a bit odd.

Comment: Getting a badge for adding all the tags yourself sounds like a bug, though.

Comment: While we're on the subject: Does removing the tag also get rid of the related badge? Otherwise, we can relatively easily game the system by quickly editing a new tag into a bunch of questions.

Comment: Interestingly I added text to the tag [devanagari] tag today since it looked reasonable to have discussions about such types of building block letters. I was contemplating flagging them for mods instead

Comment: @Cerbrus Does anyone really care?

Comment: Obviously I do, @VladimirF. I think I categorize as part of _"Anyone"_

Comment: @Cerbrus One can game many badges. For example, I can delete some well received answer of mine and I would get the Disciplined badge. Do you really care if I get the badge that way or not or whether I have the badge as of now or not?

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: @Cerberus The point is that you probably don't give a damn whether I delete and then undelete a question and get the Disciplined. Why do you care if someone  gets a badge for creating tags that are then deleted. It is even harder then just delete and undelete an answer.

Comment: That sounds rather orthogonal to the concern @VladimirF. The fact that other badges are easy to game, does not mean that we shouldn't care about all badges that, and the way in which they, can be gamed.

Comment: Also, the fact that badges *can be* gamed doesn't mean that one *should* game them.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I don't see any use for this tag.

Here are the [criteria to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/349538):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   It's certainly not unambiguous. The tag wiki excerpt (which is written by the user who created the tag) mentions several different uses that are unrelated to each other (Russian alphabet, Russian money, Russian sites, etc).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   It depends. In some cases it may be, but in other cases it isn't. The tag wiki is really too broad to say anything more.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   Not usually. Most of the questions tagged [russian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian) are about encoding issues with the Russian alphabet, but there is already a [cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic) tag there, so adding the [russian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian) tag to questions tagged [cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic) doesn't really add any meaningful information. For the other uses, I'm not sure we need a tag about Russian sites in general, and if we really do, it would probably be better to create a tag for each individual site. I don't either think we need a tag for Russian money. If the issue is related to the currency, there is already a [currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency) tag. I'm not sure we need a tag for each currency (for example, there is no [dollar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dollar) tag).
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No. Here is the tag wiki excerpt:

   > The Russian tag is for issues relating to displaying user interfaces and managing data in Russian written language or specific questions about Russian country: Russian money (rubles), Russian search engines (for example, yandex.ru), Russian social networks (for example vk.com or odnoklassniki.ru/ok.ru).

   Seriously? It mentions at least three different uses of the tag that are completely unrelated. And as I explained before I don't think we need any new tag for any of those uses.

So go ahead and roll back the edits that added the [russian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian) tag.

Comment: I'll write answer today later, please don't do roll back before

Comment: How about a quick summary of your intended answer, @ViacheslavVedenin? I've got some time to spare, and wouldn't mind unilaterally rolling back some tag someone unilaterally decided needed to exist. (You didn't discuss the need for this tag before adding it, so why do we need to discuss it now?)

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin: That's not how this works.  You created this tag by yourself with no discussion.  Going by the votes here, the community seems to pretty strongly disagree with that decision.  You don't really have the right to demand we wait for your explanation before undoing it.

Comment: Quite a lot of those questions are answered with some version of _"Use UTF-8"_. Those issues aren't specific to russian. I'm seriously considering editing the tag out. Especially considering @Viacheslav has been active on meta in the last half hour, but hasn't bothered to respond yet.

Comment: I've killed the tag completely, siding with just using the existing [tag:cyrillic] tag instead. @ViacheslavVedenin this was a wildly inappropriate use of your time. You should not conduct such efforts in the future without discussing on Meta *first*.

Comment: ^ The hero we need but don't deserve. [meta-tag:status-completed] :D

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin: I'd recommend un-deleting your answer.  Downvotes on meta don't hurt your rep or get you banned.  I think it's good that you explained your reasoning, so future readers (without enough rep to see deleted answers) can understand why you thought it was a good idea at the time.  Your reasoning makes sense, it's just based on some assumptions not shared by most people about how specific tags should be for character sets.  (If you've changed your mind, too, maybe edit your answer to say that at the top, and present it as what you were thinking when you made the edits.)

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin Please, undelete your answer.  I actually think your argument makes sense, even if not for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Brad you can just vote to undelete...

Comment: I undeleted answer

Comment: @animuson If I search for Russian, the top 3 results with the `cyrillic` tag (https://stackoverflow.com/q/20665622/1709587, https://stackoverflow.com/q/17905207/1709587, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13475419/1709587) are about *Russian* specifically but have nothing to do with the Cyrillic alphabet. All these questions are now outright incorrectly tagged as a result of your actions. Maybe the Russian tag shouldn't have existed (I'm not yet persuaded either way), but *this* cannot possibly have been the right resolution.

Comment: @MarkAmery So remove the tag from the incorrectly tagged ones?

Comment: @animuson I have no way to find all of them now, unless I go through the entire `cyrillic` tag or through Viacheslav's revision history. That's kind of the point.

Comment: @animuson And more to the point, I'm not *supposed* to go and mess with those questions yet, because we have [a process for burninating tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/1709587), designed to prevent precisely this sort of mess. You took an action here on a tag with >50 questions that *nobody* had suggested taking, without any warning and chance for community input. That should never have happened.

Comment: @MarkAmery Please stop trying to blow things out of proportion here. I looked through the list and all the questions I saw were about Cyrillic characters. This isn't a standard burnination request. This was handling a tag that should not have been created in the first place, out of nowhere. Sure, it's possible that I missed a few that were fairly edge-case examples, but I'm not going to continue an argument with you over something so silly.

Comment: Yeah, classic ambiguous tag.

Comment: *"This isn't a standard burnination request. This was handling a tag that should not have been created in the first place"* - that sounds like a description of every single correct burnination request to me; I see nothing non-standard besides the fact that this one was caught *quickly*. *"out of nowhere"* - but... that's how *all* tags are created.

Comment: @animuson anyway, a load of my time and 13 edits later, I've done the "silly" work that should never have been necessary and the 20% of these questions that had *nothing whatsoever* to do with Cyrillic characters and that *you* added the `cyrillic` tag to are now untagged. There are plenty that it didn't really add value to (particularly, around Russian keyboard layouts) but where it was at least plausibly sort-of-relevant; I've left those alone. You're welcome.

Answer (score -35):

**Main reason:**

1. Tag [cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic) is too broad. Please see this link: [Cyrillic alphabets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_alphabets):

   **The Russian alphabet**

   > А а   Б б В в Г  г    Д д Е е Ё ё Ж ж З з И и Й й К к Л л М м Н н О о П п Р
   >   р С с Т т У у Ф ф Х х Ц ц Ч ч Ш ш Щ щ Ъ ъ Ы ы Ь ь

   **The Serbian alphabet**

   > А а   Б б В в Г г Д д **Ђ ђ** Е е Ж ж З з И и
   >   **Ј ј**   К к Л л **Љ љ** М м Н н **Њ њ** О о П п Р р С с Т т **Ћ ћ** У у Ф ф Х х Ц ц Ч ч **Џ џ   Ш ш**

   **The Macedonian alphabet**

   > А а   Б б В в Г г Д д **Ѓ ѓ** Е е Ж ж З з Ѕ ѕ И и
   >   **Ј ј**   К к Л л **Љ љ** М м Н н **Њ њ** О о П п Р р С с Т т **Ќ ќ** У у Ф ф Х х Ц ц Ч ч **Џ џ** Ш ш

   Questions about Russian localisation/languages  is absolutely useless in the most case for Serbian localisation/languages and otherwise (different grammar rules, chars, code pages, alphabet and so on).
2. Why we have [turkish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turkish) tag (145 question) and [turkey-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turkey-test) (3 questions), if the Turkish languages use just latinic alphabet?

   **The Turkish alphabet**

   > A a   B b C c Ç ç D d E e F f G g Ğ ğ H h I ı İ i J jK k  L l     M m     N n O
   >   o     Ö ö P p R r S s     Ş ş     T t U u     Ü ü     V v     Y y     Z z
3. Word [cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic) is rare used and known in Russian and other Slavic languages, for that reason, no one thinking about using [cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic) tag (also very few users know about this tag). Just 399 questions about all localisation, however just words

   - [Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Russian) - 10,346 results in SO,
   - [Ukrainian](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Ukrainian) - 736  results in SO,
   - [Serbian](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Serbian) - 567 results

   and so on, tag [cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic) is a quite useless, better use [localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization), [codepages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codepages), [non-english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-english) tags and so on (because, one cyrillic language absolute different from another cyrillic language for localization and developing software)
4. Also, now we have such tags like [chinese-locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chinese-locale) and [japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/japanese) . Do you think make sense use one tag instead of [chinese-locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chinese-locale) and [japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/japanese)? Russian and, for example, Serbian languages may be more different in writing then Chinese and Japanese (in fact, I amn't  sure about it).

Comment: The Latin latin  character set is not the same as the English latin character set or French set or Czech set, but we won't use tags for all of them.

Comment: You're using a bunch of tags that should probably be burninated as an example as to why `[russian]` should stay. I'd say: Burninate those tags.

Comment: Ehm... were you really planning to edit the tag into 10,000 questions? Please no.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's not an unreasonable assumption... but (cc:) Viacheslav Vefenin _should_ have checked here on meta first.

Comment: First time ever that I see `I amn't`... Love it!

Comment: @brasofilo `amn't` is used commonly here in Ireland :)

Comment: IIRC, The Turkish UTF-8 locale is a special case because for example `toupper('i')` (ASCII) is `'İ'` (U0130 non-ASCII), not `'I'`(ASCII).  So [an optimized uppercase-region function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case/37151084#37151084) that checks for the ASCII alphabet range and uses `c &= ~0x20` to clear the lower-case bit doesn't work in the Turkish locale (or has to check for the exception character specially).  IDK if this warrants a tag, but it's certainly something to be aware of if you're optimizing string functions.

Comment: Oh, that's what the `[turkey-test]` tag is about. :P