# Should the [korean] tag be burninated/deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [korean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/korean) tag has only one question, no usage guidance and no tag wiki.  IMO, the tag doesn't add anything valuable to the post and the site in general.

Also refer to a related question about the [russian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian) tag: [Should we roll back 62 edits where [russian] was added?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359838/should-we-roll-back-62-edits-where-russian-was-added)

Comment: For the record, I was the one to create the tag, based on [tag:Japanese]. And I did attempt to add usage guidance, but [it wasn't approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20151142).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370313/make-japanese-korean-and-chinese-synonyms-of-cjk

Comment: If a tag has but one question, removing the tag from that question leads to the tag being removed automatically within 24 hours.  Replacing the tag with a more appropriate one ([tag:cjk] judging from the answer) makes it a no-brainer and the deletion will be automatic and doesn't need to involve "burnination".  Burnination is far too heavy-weight a process for a tag with but one question.  Arguably, it is best if someone with 2K+ reputation does the edit — that saves troubling the review queues.

Comment: For that small of tags, you don't need to ask Meta. For under 50 questions, you can burn the tag if you understand the topics involved and get buy-in from a 20k+ user.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since we already have [southeast-asian-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/southeast-asian-languages), which is a tag with 42 questions, of which 5 mention korean as a language, and since it's only one question, I've retagged that question.

I don't see this as a burninate, just increasing findability by moving it to a more frequently used tag.

<sub>Link to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36904221/7296893), to make rollbacks possible if people disagree with my approach</sub>

---

Edit: As suggested by [kaiido](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido), I've moved the question to [cjk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cjk), which is a better fit since it's specific to Chinese, Japanese and Korean, while [southeast-asian-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/southeast-asian-languages) focusses on another distinct set of Asian languages

Comment: I have serious doubts that question is on-topic to begin with as it appears to be missing crucial information to reproduce the problem. Voted to close accordingly.

Comment: Good idea to retag the post (despite the fact that it may be off-topic). But it feels not right to me to leave the tag alive (especially in it's current state), maybe add it as a synonym of [tag:southeast-asian-languages]?

Comment: @Filnor Any tag with 0 questions will automatically get destroyed after a day. Thus the tag won't be _alive_ anymore soon.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Nice, I didn't know that. In that case, we should be fine.

Comment: Isn't [`[cjk]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cjk/info) a better target though? 571 question as of now. [southeast-asian-languages] seems to focus more on "*Burmese (Myanmar), Khmer (Cambodian), Lao, Thai, and Vietnamese*"

Comment: @Kaiido It's certainly a better target. I wasn't aware of that abbreviation, which made the tag hard to find for me. I've moved the question to it. For merging, I suggest you open up a separate discussion.

Comment: No actually, I was wrong, merging is not a good idea. cjk is really only for Chinese Korean and Japanese (with their own variants) while [southeast-asian-languages] tag seems to focus on other languages. But I am more concerned about your answer's content, if someone comes here wanting to create the [korean]  tag, they should rather be redirected to [cjk]

Comment: As stated in my above comment on this question, I originally made the tag [tag:korean] to match [tag:japanese], and there was usage guidance pending approval prior to this meta question, but it got invalidated by the destruction of the tag after your retagging. Now, I wonder if we should make [tag:japanese] (and [tag:korean] and [tag:chinese]) synonyms of [tag:cjk] to avoid this in the future.

Comment: @Cœur That sounds like a good plan, since that also makes [tag:cjk] a little more findable, now it's just 3 pseudorandom letters. I would certainly support that if you open up a post.

Comment: My synonym request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370313/make-japanese-korean-and-chinese-synonyms-of-cjk

Comment: For people who work with mulitbyte character [cjk] is a standard acronym.  Since Korea is not in Southeast Asia it wouldn't make sense to add it there. Those languages have their own special issues.