# Make [japanese], [korean] and [chinese] synonyms of [cjk]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Yesterday, I attempted to create the tag [korean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/korean) to match the tag [japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/japanese), but the tag edit process ([in review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20151142) because I have less than 20,000 reputation) was invalidated following [Filnor meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370263/should-the-korean-tag-be-burninated-deleted?cb=1) and Erik von Asmuth retagging, probably for the best.

It was discovered, by Kaiido, that there is a likely fitting existing tag for Korean questions: [cjk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cjk).

*CJK* stands for "*Chinese/Japanese/Korean characters*".

- [cjk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cjk): 572 questions
- [chinese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chinese): 0 questions
- [japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/japanese): 95 questions
- [korean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/korean): 0 questions

I've reviewed all the 95 [japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/japanese) questions, and all of them are about characters/encoding/text except four of them about calendar locale. None of them is about nationality or voice.

Among the 95 Japanese questions, here are the only ones unrelated to characters/text:

- [Need help formatting a date in MomentJS in Japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155774/need-help-formatting-a-date-in-momentjs-in-japanese)
- [How to convert a year to the japanese calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358148/how-to-convert-a-year-to-the-japanese-calendar)
- [Convert Japanese Time format (H29.12.1) to YYYY-MM-DD format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455189/convert-japanese-time-format-h29-12-1-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-python)
- [How to localize timezone 'z' for a date format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602887/how-to-localize-timezone-z-for-a-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-a-z)

To avoid mistakes like the one I made yesterday, and for easier accessibility, I'm making this proposal:

1. We retag the 4 questions about Japanese calendar locale to [calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calendar) or [locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locale)
2. We make [japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/japanese), [korean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/korean) and [chinese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chinese) synonyms of [cjk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cjk)

Comment: I strongly support this request, as it would increase findability of this tag, which is a problem. There are, for example, [22,582 questions containing Chinese somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chinese), with no way to easily filter the ones about the language or characters, but a quick inspection shows many are. Also, as the linked question shows, I couldn't find the appropriate tag after specifically searching for it.

Comment: If we need these tags, then I propose that they are named [tag:japanese-locale] and so on. Since questions about Japanese locale are on-topic, but not questions _in_ Japanese, or whatever other reasons people might come up with to use the tag. Take for example: [tag:hungarian-notation]. Suppose someone wants to add a tag for Hungarian locale. There will be major tag confusion. Best to be as specific as possible from the start.

Comment: @Lundin Isn't [japanese-characters] , etc. better in that case?

Comment: @DavidMulder Locale could be other things than language and font though. Currency, decimal comma etc.

Comment: @Lundin That was the point, [japanese-characters] is about something technical. [japanese-locale] seems to be about a group of technically unrelated things. The entire question is about a proposal differentiating those items.

Comment: Let me say that I have no experience working with non-native characters in programming, but to me `cjk` seems rather vague, no? I would never have guessed that stood for chinese, japanese and korean if I saw it on its own.

Comment: @dwirony which is one of the reasons I believe these tag synonyms are being suggested.

Comment: @dwirony When you add the [tag:japanese] if there is a synonym, it will say "I think you want [tag:cjk]".

Comment: @dwirony Its a fairly common acronym for people dealing with the characters, but yeah, you're not gonna hear it aside from that. E.g.: google makes a set of fonts they call "Noto CJK" , and there a lot besides just the google ones that do the same. Unicode uses the term "CJK Unified Ideographs" to refer to the shared, standardised set.

Comment: @dwirony Both Japanese (Kanji) and Korean (Hanja) use Chinese characters (Vietnam also used to use them) and Unicode tried to unify them which is why CJK is a common term when talking about Unicode and character encodings.

Comment: @Anders we should make [`cjkv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJKV) a synonym to [tag:cjv] as well

Comment: @phuclv You mean [tag:cjk], no? We don't have [tag:cjv].

Comment: @Cœur sorry I didn't look at the latter. I meant [tag:cjk]

Comment: Doesn't it mean that a question about the Japanese calendar tagged with [tag:japanese] and [tag:calendar] would be incorrectly tagged then?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Currently, there is no description on the tag, so it's hard to say. In the future, if the request is approved and implemented, there wouldn't be any [japanese] tag anymore: it would display and convert itself to [cjk]. If you're talking about one of the four existing questions that I listed above, then we would remove the [japanese] tag on those before making the synonym change.

Comment: Not many people know that CJK stands for Chinese, Japanese and Korean. For that perhaps [northeast-asian-languages] or [east-asian-languages] could also be a synonym to [cjk] considering the fact that there is [southeast-asian-languages]? Because, I'm a native in S.Korea and I hear those terms `Northeast Asia` and `East Asia` quite commonly used in our language to refer to [the region where CJK(V) countries located in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_cultural_sphere). It would be helpful for people who look for relevant subjects that matter to them