# Should we make [kannada] a synonym of [indic]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request, languages

Today I discovered the following two tags:

- [kannada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kannada): 15 questions

  > Kannada is a Brahmic alphabet script used primarily in India. Use this tag for when you are dealing with applications of the Kannada alphabet or script in a program or website.
- [indic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indic): 49 questions

  > Indic scripts are the writing systems that are used by languages spoken by about two billion people in India and its neighboring countries, as well is Southeast Asian countries such as Thailand, Burma, Laos, Cambodia and Indonesia. These scripts developed from the ancient Brahmic script and share similar features, which make them challenging for use in computers: many ligatures, complex letter ordering rules and partial support in common operating systems.

So both tags are related to Brahmic scripts.

As I remember a similar case regarding Asian scripts ([Make [japanese], [korean] and [chinese] synonyms of [cjk]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370313/make-japanese-korean-and-chinese-synonyms-of-cjk)), **should we make [kannada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kannada) synonym of [indic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indic)?**

Comment: Well, I know one moderator who is an expert on this ;)

Comment: That makes about as much sense as merging [french] into [latin].  Won't happen either, you don't mess with people that have access to thermonuclear devices.  Small tags are not a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll retract my synonym votes on [tag:blame] and [tag:dry].

Comment: @Cœur ... and I was thinking of Bhargav Rao...

Comment: Of course the answer would be "no", but I was looking for more insight about why it would be "no". Unlike 漢字 where you just put rectangle after another, the rendering of Kannada script is somewhat more complicated and while same problems do appear in other Indic scripts, then there still are some unique aspects I believe.

Comment: Kannada and indic aren't the same....

Comment: @Antti ... Thanks for that, I had a strange feeling of authority when I added the [status-declined] tag to this post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*tl;dr* No.

That *both tags are related to Brahmic scripts* does not make them synonyms (tag [kannada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kannada) is a subset of tag [indic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indic)). The former is doing no harm and though applied to very few questions so far it is a relatively new creation.

[Leave well alone](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leave-well-alone).

Answer (score 2):

As a native Kannada speaker, I can tell you that Kannada while being a subclass of Indic, is very different from Indic. Indic is basically a bunch of related scripts of which Kannada is one. It also happens to be the language spoken by about 44 million people in southern India.[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers_in_India)